# How to handle multiple forms and submit in angular typescript including showing and hiding of components?

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I only use 1 component for my login , verify email , set username and password , all in single html file and with 1 ts file.

My question is , if there is code value returned from this.userService.getCode I only wanna show verify email form and hide other forms and if I click submit only the fields and data from the verify form would be submitted else if no code then only show login form and when submit is click only submit the data from the login form. What is the efficient and clean way to do this in angular guys?. Help and suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

#ts code

```
 ngOnInit(): void {      

    this.router.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
      this.authKey = paramMap.get('authkey')
    });

    if (this.authKey !== null) {
      console.log("Auth key" , this.authKey)
      this.userService.getCode(4, this.authKey).subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
          console.log("res", res)
        },
        (err: any) => {
          // this.notificationService.showError('Something went wrong, Try again later.');
        }
      );
    } else {
      // this._notificationService.showError('Something went wrong, Try again later.');
    }
  }
```

#loginForm

```
<div class="login-container-section">
      <form [formGroup]="loginForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">    
        <div id="login-form">
            <button mat-raised-button class="full-width v-btn-lrg" color="primary" type="submit" [disabled]="hasSubmit">SUBMIT</button>            
            <mat-divider class="relative"></mat-divider>
          </div>    
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

#verify email form

```
<div class="verify-container-section">
      <form [formGroup]="verifyForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">    
        <div id="verify-form">
            <button mat-raised-button class="full-width v-btn-lrg" color="primary" type="submit" [disabled]="hasSubmit">SUBMIT</button>            
            <mat-divider class="relative"></mat-divider>
          </div>    
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

#set username and password form

```
<div class="setaccount-container-section">
      <form [formGroup]="setAccountForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">    
        <div id="setaccount-form">
            <button mat-raised-button class="full-width v-btn-lrg" color="primary" type="submit" [disabled]="hasSubmit">SUBMIT</button>            
            <mat-divider class="relative"></mat-divider>
          </div>    
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is with a status var that has the value of a enum with all your possible status, like:

```
enum FormStatus {
  LOGIN = 1;
  VERIFY_EMAIL = 2;
  ...
}

...

generalStatus = FormStatus.LOGIN;
```

And set in all your html divs `*ngIf` like `*ngIf="generalStauts === FormStatus.LOGIN"`, etc.

And with your logic, throught buttons or requests response change this value to update the part of your UI that you want to render. A very simple pattern. Also if you have few forms, you can validate one or another based on the same key.

Comment: Thanks @Juan Antonio,  how about the formGroup Sir ? Do I need to create 3 seperate formgroup?. Can you please provide a multiple fromgroup example sir each with seperate submit ?

Comment: You are welcome @JhonCaylog :)
Yes, the best option is to have separate forms because probably you will have different way to validate them. And after you only need validate one or another based on the same key.

Comment: Do you have some example just a small example Sir I can based and check on ? just how the multiple froms could have seperate submission on the ts and html file. Thank you,

Comment: I can't but I found [it example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/login-register-angular-material?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnavbar%2Fnavbar.component.html) on stackblitz. Try to join on the same page with your login or evaluate this way to separate on diferent pages, is a bit more complex but you will have your code more separate.

Comment: If all the functions are on the same files sir and in single html contains all the forms  , is it better to use submit ? or user click to call a specific function ? Thanks.

Comment: Each div (for example) with each form inside with their own click to call their own submit method is a way but to avoid to repeat code, you can only have one button with only one method to validate and send the data of the form that your control var says.